# How to create a boxplot of survey data in R?

Tags: r, boxplot

I am using data where respondents give a score from *0-10* and I am trying to create box plot of these responses by region. However, the box plots will not form and no error message comes up either.

I changed the response scores to factors and this seemed to help as the scores from 0-10 showed up on the `x axis` and the different regions appeared on the `y axis`. However, the box plots still did not show up. Instead, the graph contained dots at each coordinate. I tried to change the region into factors but it made things worse.

Creating boxplots to compare differences in financial satisfaction within and between regions.

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
Regional.Difference<-ggplot(ons2, aes(x=Region, y='Financial Satisfaction'))
Regional.Difference+geom_boxplot()+coord_flip()
```

I am hoping to get a box plot for each region's financial satisfaction, so I can compare medians and inter-quartile range across regions.

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset for ons2 that makes your code reproducible. For example use `dput(ons2)` and paste the code here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! will use it the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and generated some data, but it may not be like what you're working with:

```
ons2 <- data.table(round(runif(1000,1,10), 0), rep(c('Region 1', 'Region 2', 'Region 3', 'Region 4', 'Region 5')))
colnames(ons2) <- c("Response", "Region")

Regional.Difference<-ggplot(ons2, aes(x=Region, y=Response))
Regional.Difference+geom_boxplot()+ylab('Financial Satisfaction')+coord_flip()
```

This gives the below. Looks like you're mostly just missing the grouping.

[image]